# How to retrieve certain user fields using Rally REST API?

Tags: rest, rally

When I query Rally REST API (.net) I am able to get all the user values except the following fields:

1. Role
2. CostCenter
3. LastLoginDate
4. OfficeLocation
5. c_RoleType
6. CreationDate

When I fire up a url "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user/xxxxxxxxxx" in a browser I am able to access all the above fields.

However, when I use REST API the result set doesn't include any of the above fields.

Not sure if I need to do anything differently.

```
request = new Request("user");
request.Fetch = fetchList;
request.Workspace = RallyInterface.workspaceRef;
QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(request);
```

PS. In above example Fetch string is empty and the aim is to fetch all the possible user fields. When I debug I am only able to get the following 18 fields

```
    [0] "_rallyAPIMajor"    string
    [1] "_rallyAPIMinor"    string
    [2] "_ref"  string
    [3] "_refObjectUUID"    string
    [4] "_objectVersion"    string
    [5] "_refObjectName"    string
    [6] "ObjectID"  string
    [7] "Department"    string
    [8] "Disabled"  string
    [9] "DisplayName"   string
    [10]    "EmailAddress"  string
    [11]    "FirstName" string
    [12]    "LastName"  string
    [13]    "MiddleName"    string
    [14]    "Phone" string
    [15]    "Role"  string
    [16]    "UserName"  string
    [17]    "_type" string
```

Also, when I use GetByReference(), I am able to get the value for "Role" but not for any of the following fields:

1. CostCenter
2. LastLoginDate
3. OfficeLocation
4. c_RoleType
5. CreationDate

GetByReference() response returns with field not found message.

Comment: what fields are you fetching in your fetchList ?

Comment: I have an empty fetch list I.e. I am fetching all the fields. However, only thing I am doing differently to your code is not filtering the query by user name/email. When I debug I get the following list as response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fetchList` should include those fields, or should be entirely omitted. The code example below returns those fields in both cases. It means if I comment out `userRequest.Fetch` in the code below, those fields will still be returned. If a fetch is present, but does not include those fields, they will not be returned.

```
            userRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
                {
                   "Role",
                   "CostCenter",
                   "LastLoginDate",
                   "OfficeLocation",
                   "CreationDate"
                };

            userRequest.Query = new Query("UserName", Query.Operator.Equals, "user@co.com");

            QueryResult userResults = restApi.Query(userRequest);

            foreach (var u in userResults.Results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Role: " + u["Role"] + " CostCenter: " + u["CostCenter"] + " LastLoginDate: " + u["LastLoginDate"] + " OfficeLocation: " + u["OfficeLocation"] + " CreationDate: " + u["CreationDate"]);
            }
```

Here is another variation of this code when `GetByReference` is used:

```
userRequest.Query = new Query("UserName", Query.Operator.Equals, "user@co.com");

        QueryResult userResults = restApi.Query(userRequest);
        String userRef = userResults.Results.First()._ref;
        DynamicJsonObject user = restApi.GetByReference(userRef, "Name", "Role", "CostCenter", "LastLoginDate", "OfficeLocation", "CreationDate");
        String role = user["Role"];
        String costCenter = user["CostCenter"];
        String lastLoginDate = user["LastLoginDate"];
        String officeLocation = user["OfficeLocation"];
        String creationDate = user["CreationDate"];

        Console.WriteLine("Role: " + role + " CostCenter: " + costCenter + " LastLoginDate: " + lastLoginDate + " OfficeLocation: " + officeLocation + " CreationDate: " + creationDate);
```

The full code is available in [this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/rally-dot-net-rest-apps/blob/master/getUserInfo.cs).

Comment: I have an empty fetch list I.e. I am fetching all the fields. However, only thing I am doing differently to your code is not filtering the query by user name/email. When I debug I get the following list as response

Comment: Please refer to my additional info for more details on what fields are being returned in the Response. Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: What is the exact wording of "Field not found" message you mentioned? Are you getting "Unhandled Exception: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given
key was not present in the dictionary." ? With what permissions are you running this code? A workspace admin? An editor?

Comment: Thanks a ton Nick. It was my oversight on not checking the permissions. Assumed I was using a user with subscription admin rights. The user had only user level permissions.